# angular directives - Parent calls children isolated scope method

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-directive

In my angular app I've got a parent directive, say a list of some sort, that contains many child directives, say items.

I'd like to be able to call a certain method on the children from the parent. I know in advance what children I'd be calling (by an input of start and end index of the items list). Therefore I wish to avoid using broadcast, as I don't want to call all children but just a selected few.

Both the children and the parent have their own isolated scopes.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: do you have to make an action (like click on the item) to do this call or it should be done right after loading the page?

Comment: it depends on user interaction, like clicking a button etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to create `controllers` for your parent directive. That is accessible for your children directives, it's some kind of shared functions for your children directives. Then you can register a function which can add new functions to the parent controllers that u can later execute.
Let me show you with a quick example (maybe it won't work with copy-paste, its just the theory how should it look like)

```
//parent directive's controller function
function ParentControllerFunction(){
    this.arrayOfChildFuncions = [];
}

//your child directive's link function
require: '^ParentControllerFunction'
link: function(scope, element, attr, ctrl){
    function myLittleFunction(){
       //hhere is your function that you can call
    }

    ctrl.arrayOfChildFuncions.push(myLittleFunction);
}
```

Then later on you can execute your functions depending on which one do you want to:

```
//executes the 3rd directive's function with the parameter 'hello'
arrayOfChildFuncions[3]('hello')
```

Comment: interesting approach, what do you think of this? It seems a bit hacky. What happens if children change order inside parent, how would I then know what function is the matching one?

Comment: Then you need some kind of identification for each and add it in that way.
like: `objectOfChildFunctions[item.id] = myLittleFunction;`
So that from your controller you can call the proper item's function.

Answer (score 0):

you can use $index in order to get the desired directive from ng-repeat, and then call your function.
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Comment: Can u maybe provide an example? I'm not sure how to achieve this using $index